# GA Tracker Names in new analytics.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Hello Guys o/ So i need to set a tracker names in Google analytics, before in old ga.js i have:

```
_gaq.push(['TrackerFoo._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['TrackerFoo._setDomainName', 'sub.domain.com']);
```

In new analytics.js i have a send and create method:

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'domain.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

how can i set a TrackerFoo for setAccount, setDomain and others in new analytics.js? i googled and searched in google documentations and found nothing, someone know how to deal with it?

Comment: @TomFuertes - changing the original question & answers to fix terminology doesn't allow others to learn from mistakes. Please keep that in mind when making edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below shows a namespace of "TrackerFoo"

```
_gaq.push(['TrackerFoo._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['TrackerFoo._setDomainName', 'sub.domain.com']);
```

Which would equate to this in analytics.js:

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'domain.com', {'name': 'TrackerFoo'});
ga('TrackerFoo.send', 'pageview');
```

[Relevant documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#name)

Comment: thanks, and this docs are really good :) this is what i want!